# multi array: find the sum of all numbers under minor diagonal

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I cannot find a way to sum all the numbers that are under antidiagonal. (Right top to left bottom)

```
1 1 0
1 0 2
0 2 2
```

Here is an example of an array, I want to find the sum of all the numbers 2, but unfortunately I can't think of how. At the moment I can find sum the numbers 1.
How to find the sum of numbers 2. Regardless of the size of the array.
My code:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < a[i].length; ++j) {
        sum += a[i][j - 1 - i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try writing down, on paper, a 5x5 grid of boxes.  Imagine this is your array.  Now, fill in the boxes that you want to be considered for summation.  Next to each row, write the index of the first column that you filled in on that row.  Do you see the pattern?  Turn that into the logic that drives your inner loop range.  Hint: it will be the opposite of whatever you did when you summed the upper left triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, you may notice that for every `i`, you have to sum from `j = last 1` to `j = last i`.

```
1 1 0 <-- i=0: nothing
1 0 2 <-- i=1: j = last 1
0 2 2 <-- i=2: j = last 1, last 2
```

If you didn't, try to use more examples to help understanding:

```
1 1 1 0 <-- i=0: nothing
1 1 0 2 <-- i=1: j = last 1
1 0 2 2 <-- i=2: j = last 1 ~ last 2
0 2 2 2 <-- i=3: j = last 1 ~ last 3

1 1 1 1 0 <-- i=0: nothing
1 1 1 0 2 <-- i=1: j = last 1
1 1 0 2 2 <-- i=2: j = last 1 ~ last 2
1 0 2 2 2 <-- i=3: j = last 1 ~ last 3
0 2 2 2 2 <-- i=4: j = last 1 ~ last 4
```

Next, the index of `last 1` is `a[i].length-1`, the index of `last 2` is `a[i].length-2`, and so on. Therefore, the index of `last i` is `a[i].length-i`.

Summarizing the above, you have to sum from `j=a[i].length-1` to `j=a[i].length-i`, and `i=0` to `i=a.length-1`. This is also the answer:

```c
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for(int j = a[i].length-1; j >= a[i].length-i; --j) {
        sum += a[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: my program load endlessly on the second parameter of the second for-loop. what could be the problem?

`for(int j = matrix[i].length-1; j >= matrix[i].length-i; ++j)`

Comment: `matrix[i].length-1` is bigger than `matrix[i].length-i`, so you should use `--j` instead of `++j`

Comment: I missed --j
Thank you, your answer explains a lot.

Comment: If you want to use `++j`, you can loop in reverse order: `for(int j = a[i].length-i; j <= a[i].length-1; ++j)` or `for(int j = a[i].length-i; j < a[i].length; ++j)`